# python system calls

Tags: python, shell

with this command, I get only the file called OUTPUT (in reality I have many more --include flags) - so works as expected:

```
os.system("rsync --rsh=ssh -arvuP --include='OUTPUT' --exclude='*' user@host:there/ ./here")
```

In this case, the --include and --exclude flags are ignored:

```
subprocess.call("rsync --rsh=ssh -arvuP --include='OUTPUT' --exclude='*' user@host:there/ ./here".split())
```

I wonder what I am doing wrong? Thank you much!

Edit: Sorry, this is on OS X Leopard, and I get all the files...

Comment: when you say "the --include and --exclude flags are ignored:" are you getting ALL files are NO files?

Comment: You don't specify whether this is on Linux, Windows or some other OS.  That's pretty important to debugging this.

Answer (score 3):

Try using `subprocess.call` with `shell=True`, it will simulate os.system more closely:

```
subprocess.call("...", shell=True)
```

Comment: Thanks - but no luck. When I run with shell=True, it is as if I had typed rsync without any arguments...

Answer (score 1):

Python does have an rsync module if I am not wrong, why not use that instead of a call. It will make your app more manageable.

Comment: Ah, I did not know about that module - thanks for the tip. I'm curious as to the behavior of subprocess.call in this case though, as I feel I've followed the instructions and examples on how to use it closely - without success...